# MySQL: Select value where date between two dates. If date/value does not exist display date and value 0

Tags: mysql, sql, date, left-join

I have this table:

```
+------------+---------+--------+----------+
| date       | regular | deduct | overtime |
+------------+---------+--------+----------+
| 2018-01-01 | 8       | 0      | 0        |
+------------+---------+--------+----------+
| 2018-01-03 | 8       | 0      | 0        |
+------------+---------+--------+----------+
| 2018-01-04 | 8       | 0      | 1        |
+------------+---------+--------+----------+
| 2018-01-09 | 8       | 2      | 0        |
+------------+---------+--------+----------+
```

And i want to select:

1. Everything between 2018-01-01 and 2018-01-09
2. Hours = regular - deduct + overtime
3. If date not found, display with hours = 0

to get the following result:

```
+------------+-------+
| date       | hours |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-01 | 8     |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-02 | 0     |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-03 | 0     |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-04 | 9     |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-05 | 0     |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-06 | 0     |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-07 | 0     |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-08 | 0     |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-09 | 6     |
+------------+-------+
```

This is the SQL to generate the series of dates between two dates of which works:

```
SELECT DATE(cal.date) as date
FROM ( 
      SELECT SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) + INTERVAL xc DAY AS date 
      FROM ( 
            SELECT @xi:=@xi+1 as xc from 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc1, 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc2, 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc3, 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc4, 
            (SELECT @xi:=-1) xc0 
      ) xxc1 
) cal 
WHERE cal.date >= '2018-01-01' and cal.date <= '2018-01-09'
GROUP BY DATE(cal.date)
ORDER BY cal.date ASC
```

And this is how I try to join my table above with the hours with no result:

```
SELECT DATE(cal.date) as date, IFNULL((x.regular + x.overtime - x.deduct), 0) AS hours 
FROM ( 
      SELECT SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) + INTERVAL xc DAY AS date 
      FROM ( 
            SELECT @xi:=@xi+1 as xc from 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc1, 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc2, 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc3, 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) xc4, 
            (SELECT @xi:=-1) xc0 
      ) xxc1 
) cal 
LEFT JOIN attendance x ON x.date = cal.date
WHERE cal.date >= '2018-01-01' and cal.date <= '2018-01-09'
GROUP BY DATE(cal.date)
ORDER BY cal.date ASC
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: The date range you've generated is for March 1st to March 8th but the data in your table is from January 1st to January 9th. Try generating the date range for January. Good luck!

Comment: @Brayden Dates shown are an example. If you have tried the code itself with the 'correct' dates, it would give you any result either way.

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean?

Comment: SQL is great for storing and retrieving relational data. But it's not so hot at everything else, so consider you some kind of presentation layer/application level code instead. PHP is a popular choice, but there are others

Comment: @Strawberry I am already doing the task with PHP where I came to conclusion that this way can increase performance up to 70% to the end compex result

Comment: @jQuerybeast nope, this code is quite the opposite: it reduces performance on the long run because it does not scale. The union subquery creates a temporary table every time you run this code.

Comment: While I do understand, when you have a table with 100 departments and date ranges of 60 days, for each employee then this 'could' be faster. But since I'm a practical person instead of theory; I'm on a missing to make my performance benchmarks; and this question is part of it :)

Comment: Not only will it be faster, it will be more flexible too. Sometimes poor 'practice' can undo otherwise sound theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple fix:

```
SELECT DATE(cal.date) as date, IFNULL((x.regular + x.overtime - x.deduct), 0) AS hours 
FROM (SELECT (DATE('2018-01-01') + INTERVAL xc DAY) AS date 
      FROM (SELECT (@xi := @xi + 1) as xc 
            FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) xc1 CROSS JOIN
                 (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) xc2 CROSS JOIN
                 (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) xc3 CROSS JOIN 
                 (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) xc4 CROSS JOIN 
                 (SELECT @xi:=-1) xc0 
           ) xxc1 
     ) cal LEFT JOIN
     attendance x
     ON x.date = cal.date
WHERE cal.date >= '2018-01-01' and cal.date <= '2018-01-09'
GROUP BY DATE(cal.date)
ORDER BY cal.date ASC;
```

The problem is the `JOIN` and `NOW()`.  `NOW()` as a time component, so the `JOIN` will always fail (well, unless you run at exactly midnight).

You could fix your version using `CURDATE()`, but I find the logic hard to follow, with dates relative to the present in one part of the query and fixed dates in another.

Comment: Very smart, haven't thought about the NOW() as a time component. Thanks